# Next bigger number with the same digits in codewars

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

this is a problem on CodeWars, this code runs with me but on the site doesn't work and gives me this message

---

test

expected -1 to equal 414

---

,I have a successful code that runs on codewars but I want to know the problem in this code,
the problem is

*Create a function that takes a positive integer and returns the next bigger number that can be formed by rearranging its digits. For example:*

```
nextBigger(num: 12)   // returns 21
nextBigger(num: 513)  // returns 531
nextBigger(num: 2017) // returns 2071
```

```js
function nextBigger(n) {
  //your code here
  function equal(arr) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) count++;
      if (count == arr.length - 1) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  /* function noHope(arr) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i in arr) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) count++;
    }
    if (count == arr.length - 1) return true;
    else return false;
  } */
  let str = n.toString();
  let arr = str.split("");
  let revArr = arr.reverse();
  let temp = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (revArr[i] > revArr[i + 1]) {
      temp = revArr[i];
      revArr[i] = revArr[i + 1];
      revArr[i + 1] = temp;
      break;
    } else if ((arr.length = 1 || arr.equal()) /* || arr.noHope */ ) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return parseInt(revArr.reverse().join(""));
}

console.log(nextBigger(12));
console.log(nextBigger(531));
console.log(nextBigger(2017));
console.log(nextBigger(414));
console.log(nextBigger(45222));
console.log(nextBigger(111));
console.log(nextBigger(8));
```

Comment: You are returning `-1` when `revArr[i] > revArr[i + 1]` is `false` (`arr.length = 1` is always `true` because you are *assigning* `1` to `arr.length`, you are not comparing it).

Comment: Ohh , thank you i didnt see it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two problems.

**1)** You were *setting* `arr.length` to `1` instead of comparing it (`=` vs `==`).
`if ((arr.length = 1 || arr.equal()) /* || arr.noHope */ )`
should be
`if ((arr.length == 1 || arr.equal()) /* || arr.noHope */ )`

**2)** You were attempting to call `equal()` as a method of `arr`, when you should have used `arr` as a parameter.
`if ((arr.length == 1 || arr.equal()) /* || arr.noHope */ )`
should be
`if ((arr.length == 1 || equal(arr)) /* || arr.noHope */ )`

```js
function nextBigger(n) {
  //your code here
  function equal(arr) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) count++;
      if (count == arr.length - 1) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  /* function noHope(arr) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i in arr) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) count++;
    }
    if (count == arr.length - 1) return true;
    else return false;
  } */
  let str = n.toString();
  let arr = str.split("");
  let revArr = arr.reverse();
  let temp = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (revArr[i] > revArr[i + 1]) {
      temp = revArr[i];
      revArr[i] = revArr[i + 1];
      revArr[i + 1] = temp;
      break;
    } else if ((arr.length == 1 || equal(arr)) /* || arr.noHope */ ) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return parseInt(revArr.reverse().join(""));
}

console.log(nextBigger(12));
console.log(nextBigger(531));
console.log(nextBigger(2017));
console.log(nextBigger(414));
console.log(nextBigger(45222));
console.log(nextBigger(111));
console.log(nextBigger(8));
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it seems that I was drunk when I wrote that code lol, thank you so much